# How to remove this object from a Swift array?

Tags: swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

What would be an appropriate command for removing formattedCoordinate from the array? I know a removeObject exists for Objective-C, but how about Swift?

```
var markersArray: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = []

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker){
    let lat: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.latitude
    let lng: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.longitude
    var formattedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,longitude: lng)
    //markersArray.remove(formattedCoordinate) need to fix this
    self.clean()
    //    return 0; not sure if we need this here
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker){
    let lat: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.latitude
    let lng: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.longitude
    var formattedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,longitude: lng)
    // markersArray.remove(formattedCoordinate) need to fix this
}
```

Comment: Stick an at: in front of formattedCoordinate in your line with remove

Comment: See the swift language guide section on collections: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Comment: @Konyv12 array.remove(at: Index).provide the index value

Comment: With the dupe target in mind, the only remaining problem is that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` doesn't (for whatever reason) conform to `Equatable` – doing so is fairly trivial, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/27364437/2976878

Comment: But the user might click on marker that was drawn previously, so it's not always the last member of the array that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
self.markersArray = self.markersArray.filter({ !(($0.latitude == formattedCoordinate.latitude) && ($0.longitude == formattedCoordinate.longitude)) })
```

Comment: yeah, my bad, fixed it, sry.

Comment: I have a multi-dimensional array. Will this work for that?

Comment: @konyv12 haven't tried, but since filter gets a `closure`, theoretically it should, if you adapt this code to works not with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` but `[Class]`

Comment: what do you mean exactly by [Class]?